# Mudar conteúdo ao passar o mouse em uma div

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, less

Galera preciso fazer com que quando passe o mouse(hover) em uma `div` ela mude o conteúdo da lateral [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
a imagem explica bem como o processo deve ser feito quando passar o mouse em cima da `div` deve trocar os textos na lateral gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso com `hover` segue meu código:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="needs">
                            <h4 class="title">Quais são suas necessidades?</h4>
                            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                                <div onmouseover="change(1)" class="service -bg" id="p1">
                                    <i class="icon -thecnology"></i>
                                    <p class="description migration">Migração</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                                <div onmouseover="change(2)" class="service -bg"  id="p2">
                                    <i class="icon -project"></i>
                                    <p class="description project" style="white-space: nowrap">Projeto Personalizado</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                                <div onmouseover="change(3)" class="service -bg"  id="p3">
                                    <i class="icon -security"></i>
                                    <p class="description security">Segurança</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                                <div onmouseover="change(4)" class="service -bg"  id="p4">
                                    <i class="icon -optimization"></i>
                                    <p class="description optimization">Otimização</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="box-descriptions" id="content">
                        <p id="content-one" class="content one">Podemos ajudar a migrar seus aplicativos para a Origiweb, tornando essa
                            transiçao mais fácil e suave para a sua equipe.</p>

                        <p id="content-two" class="content two">Podemos ajudar a migrar seus aplicativos para a Origiweb, tornando essa
                            transiçao mais fácil e suave para a sua equipe.</p>

                        <p id="content-tree" class="content tree">Podemos ajudar a migrar seus aplicativos para a Origiweb, tornando essa
                            transiçao mais fácil e suave para a sua equipe.</p>

                        <p id="content-for" class="content four">Podemos ajudar a migrar seus aplicativos para a Origiweb, tornando essa
                            transiçao mais fácil e suave para a sua equipe.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    function change(val) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) x[i].style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('content'+val).style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Erro do console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ONMOUSEOVER**

A abordagem mais direta, através de JavaScript puro, utiliza `onmouseover` para chamar uma função e, dessa forma, alterar a exibição dos itens:

```js
function mudar(val) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('conteudo');
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) x[i].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('conteudo'+val).style.display = 'block';  
}
```

```css
.conteudo {
  display: none;
}

#conteudo1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p onmouseover="mudar(1)" id="p1">Passe o mouse aqui</p>
<p onmouseover="mudar(2)" id="p2">Passe o mouse aqui</p>
<p onmouseover="mudar(3)" id="p3">Passe o mouse aqui</p>
<p onmouseover="mudar(4)" id="p4">Passe o mouse aqui</p>

<div id="conteudo">
   <div id="conteudo1" class="conteudo um">Conteúdo 1</div>
   <div id="conteudo2" class="conteudo dois">Conteúdo 2</div>
   <div id="conteudo3" class="conteudo tres">Conteúdo 3</div>
   <div id="conteudo4" class="conteudo quatro">Conteúdo 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela resposta so uma coisa esse js tem que estar no head ou  body la em baixo ?

Comment: Uma boa prática, na verdade, é usar os scripts logo antes do fechamento do `</body>`, poucos casos que não seguem essa regra.

Comment: @Kirito se estiver correto pra ti, marca como correto, para ajudar outras pessoas também, um abraço!

Comment: só uma coisa essa tag <p onmouseover="mudar(1)" id="p1">
vou trocar por essa <div onmouseover="mudar(2)" class="service -bg"  id="p2">
 não tem probelma ser uma div certo ? ou tem que ser um <p>

Comment: Pode ser qualquer TAG, inclusive `<img>`, `<span>`, `<a>`... Só o valor 2, dentro da função `mudar(2)` eu uso para chamar a div conteudo2, se fosse 3 chamaria a 3 e assim por diante, tu compreendeu a lógica?

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta e vou colcoar com as alterações que fiz baseado no sua resposta ta dando um erro ele mostra o primeiro texto quando passo o mouse em cima da div ele some e nao aparece mais

Comment: Está editada se puder dar uma olhada e ver aonde estou errando

Comment: @Kirito é só mudar o ID de content-one para `content1` e no Javascript mudar para `document.getElementById('content'+val)`